# igraph in R - merging two graphs

Tags: r, graph, igraph, unions

I am trying to merge two graphs in R, using igraph. Ideally, I would create a union of vertices from `g1` and `g2`, keeping edges from `g1` only. This union should be created based on the `label` attribute. I guess I could simply remove all the edges from `g2` before merging, using something like this:

```
g2 %>% delete_edges(seq(1, length(E(g2)), by = 1))
```

Still, when I create a union like this:

```
g.union <- graph.union(g1, g2, byname=F)
```

I get a graph with attributes `id_1`, `id_2`, `label_1`, `label_2`, `weight_1`, `weight_2`... Which is not quite what I want. I need to retain all the vertices and edges from `g1` adding only those vertices from `g2` that are missing in `g1`. Keeping all properties of those added vertices.

Any help appreciated!

**EDIT:**

@MrFlick, I can't share those graphs, but a simple example would be something like this:

I have `g1`

```
graph
[
  directed 1
  node
  [
    id 1
    label "it2igcryfm862x"
    mydetails "somedetails1"
  ]
  node
  [
    id 2
    label "it0l2xa53eu1w3"
    mydetails "somedetails2"
  ]
  node
  [
    id 3
    label "iszyxcopnao380"
    mydetails "somedetails3"
  ]
 edge
  [
    source 1
    target 2
    weight 1
  ]
  edge
  [
    source 1
    target 3
    weight 2
  ]
  edge
  [
    source 2
    target 3
    weight 1
  ]
]
```

and `g2`

```
graph
[
  directed 1
  node
  [
    id 1
    label "it2igcryfm862x"
    mydetails "somedetails1"
  ]
  node
  [
    id 2
    label "it0l2xa53eu1w3"
    mydetails "somedetails2"
  ]
  node
  [
    id 3
    label "iszyxcopnao380"
    mydetails "somedetails3"
  ]
  node
  [
    id 4
    label "it0lhztmkln4n6"
    mydetails "somedetails4"
  ]
 edge
  [
    source 1
    target 2
    weight 1
  ]
  edge
  [
    source 1
    target 3
    weight 3
  ]
  edge
  [
    source 2
    target 3
    weight 2
  ]
  edge
  [
    source 2
    target 4
    weight 2
  ]
  edge
  [
    source 3
    target 4
    weight 1
  ]
]
```

and what I need is `g3`

```
graph
[
  directed 1
  node
  [
    id 1
    label "it2igcryfm862x"
    mydetails "somedetails1"
  ]
  node
  [
    id 2
    label "it0l2xa53eu1w3"
    mydetails "somedetails2"
  ]
  node
  [
    id 3
    label "iszyxcopnao380"
    mydetails "somedetails3"
  ]
  node
  [
    id 4
    label "it0lhztmkln4n6"
    mydetails "somedetails4"
  ]
 edge
  [
    source 1
    target 2
    weight 1
  ]
  edge
  [
    source 1
    target 3
    weight 2
  ]
  edge
  [
    source 2
    target 3
    weight 1
  ]
]
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and the desired output.

Comment: Tried to provide three simple graphs that should give a better idea what the problem is all about.

Comment: You need to provide data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). How is one supposed to load that data in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a reproducible example

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)
g1 <- make_(ring(10), with_vertex_(label = LETTERS[1:10]))
V(g1)$color = "red"
g2 <- make_(ring(15), with_vertex_(label = LETTERS[1:15]))
V(g2)$color <- "cyan"
```

You need to

> retain all the vertices and edges from g1 adding only those vertices
>   from g2 that are missing in g1. Keeping all properties of those added
>   vertices.

One way to do it:

```
v <- V(g2)[!V(g2)%in%V(g1)]
g3 <- add_vertices(g1, length(v), attr = vertex.attributes(g2, v))
```

Here's how the two original graphs and the result look like:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^g\\d")), plot)
```

[image]

Comment: Side note: one may need `g3 <- add_vertices(g1, length(v), attr = vertex.attributes(g2, v)[intersect(vertex_attr_names(g1), vertex_attr_names(g2))])` if the attributes from g1 and g2 differ, and one wants those of g2 that are also in g1...

Comment: Thanks much lukeA and @G5W. There seems to be something I'm missing here, since I'm getting this error: `Error in vertex.attributes(g2, v) : object 'value' not found`

Comment: @Srecko I cannot reproduce the error since you still did not provide a reproducible example. Two people pointed you already to the information if needed. Please read it and edit your post accordingly. The goal should be that anyone can run the code by copy-pasting, like in the answer from G5W.

Comment: Thanks, @lukeA, but I was using the code you provided. Just copied and tried to run, but got this error.

Comment: @Srecko Whats your `packageVersion("igraph")` - maybe `install.packages("igraph")`?

Comment: I thought that as well - but, it's 1.1.0.

Comment: I use igraph version `1.1.2`.

Comment: Well, there seems to be another problem :( can't install with `install.packages("igraph")`, there is an error compiling. So, installed with `install_github("igraph/rigraph")`. Guess should solve that first...

Comment: That's it, @lukeA. The problem was with the igraph library. It worked with the version 1.1.2. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your original code seems to be close to working on the example that you provided.

```
library(igraph)

###  Recreating your example
par(mfrow = c(2,2), mar=c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5))
g1 = graph_from_edgelist(matrix(c(1,2,1,3,2,3), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))
g1 = set_vertex_attr(g1, "label", 
    value=c("it2igcryfm862x", "it0l2xa53eu1w3", 
        "iszyxcopnao380"))
plot(g1)
box()

g2 = graph_from_edgelist(matrix(c(1,2,1,3,2,3,2,4,3,4), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))
g2 = set_vertex_attr(g2, "label", 
    value=c("it2igcryfm862x", "it0l2xa53eu1w3", 
        "iszyxcopnao380", "it0lhztmkln4n6"))
plot(g2)
box()

## Create the desired union
g1g2 = union(g1,delete_edges(g2, E(g2)))

## Edit: Preserving labels
NewLabels = c(vertex_attr(g1, "label"), 
    setdiff(vertex_attr(g2, "label"), vertex_attr(g1, "label")))
g1g2 = set_vertex_attr(g1g2, "label", value=NewLabels)

plot(g1g2)
box()
```

[image: Revised graph]

Comment: Thanks, G5W! This one does return all the nodes and edges as expected. But, each property is duplicated. In the example you provided it would be `attr: label_1 (v/c), label_2 (v/c)`, instead of `label`

Comment: Yes,  I see that I lost the labels in the union.  Editing answer.

Comment: Either I'm doing something wrong, or we are getting the same attribute 3 times :) I don't think it's a big deal, but when you run `vertex_attr(g1g2, index = V(g1g2))`, this is what you'll get:


`$label_1
[1] "it2igcryfm862x" "it0l2xa53eu1w3" "iszyxcopnao380" NA              

$label_2
[1] "it2igcryfm862x" "it0l2xa53eu1w3" "iszyxcopnao380" "it0lhztmkln4n6"

$label
[1] "it2igcryfm862x" "it0l2xa53eu1w3" "iszyxcopnao380" "it0lhztmkln4n6"`

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong.  The `union` operation copies the labels from g1 to the new attribute label_1. The labels from g2 go to label_2.  I created a new label attribute so that it would correctly label the picture.  You can just delete the extra label_1 and label_2.

Comment: Sure, makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Oh yes... I know there was something that bothered me :) so, when you do a simple thing `g2 = set_vertex_attr(g2, "label", 
    value=c("it2igcryfm862x", "it0lhztmkln4n6", "it0l2xa53eu1w3", 
        "iszyxcopnao380"))` - new node has an id = 2, everything gets messed up: `$label_1
[1] "it2igcryfm862x" "it0l2xa53eu1w3" "iszyxcopnao380" NA              

$label_2
[1] "it2igcryfm862x" "it0lhztmkln4n6" "it0l2xa53eu1w3" "iszyxcopnao380"

$label
[1] "it2igcryfm862x" "it0l2xa53eu1w3" "iszyxcopnao380" "it0lhztmkln4n6"`. That's why I need union by `label`. Any ideas?